# jquery find closest class and increase value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons to increase/decrease quantity in a cart

```
<div class="product-quantity">
  <button class="qtyminus">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty form-control">
  <button class="qtyplus">+</button>
</div>
```

my javascript unfortunately doesn't work can't figure out why.

```
$('.qtyplus').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = Number($(this).closest('.qty').val());
    $(this).closest('.qty').val(++num);
});
```

Comment: Is there a good reason as to why you're trying to reference the element dynamically?

Comment: yes, because its for a shopping cart and every item in the cart has its own quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery `closest` searches ancestors, but in this case, you're looking for the sibling element.  Try `siblings` instead of `closest`

By the way, modern browsers have built-in debugging tools.  It's easy to set a breakpoint and step through you code to see what's happening, and to use the console window to test things.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `siblings()` instead of `closest()` as `closest()` searches for ancestors while `siblings()` searches for siblings of an element.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-quantity">
  <button class="qtyminus">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty form-control">
  <button class="qtyplus">+</button>
</div>
<script>

$('.qtyplus').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = Number($(this).siblings('.qty').val());
    $(this).siblings('.qty').val(++num);
});
$('.qtyminus').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = Number($(this).siblings('.qty').val());
    $(this).siblings('.qty').val(--num);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because `closest()` looks up the DOM, yet `.qty` is a sibling to the clicked buttons, so you need to use `siblings()` instead.

Also note that you can use a single event handler for both buttons if you put a common class on them and provide the value to add in a `data` attribute. You can also negate the need to repeatedly select the same element by providing a function to `val()` which returns the new value based on its current one. Try this:

```js
$('.amendqty').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var inc = $(this).data('inc');
  $(this).siblings('.qty').val(function(i, v) {
    return parseInt(v, 10) + inc;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-quantity">
  <button class="amendqty" data-inc="-1">-</button>
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="qty form-control">
  <button class="amendqty" data-inc="1">+</button>
</div>
```